# Deserialize XML with variant child

Tags: c#, xml, class, object, deserialization

I have a device that generates 6 different types of XML notifications, via TCP, at random.  I am already successfully deserializing the notifications; however, 1 particular notification, event, I need some advice on how to handle it more efficiently.

Here are 3/36 examples of the event notifications:

```
Example 1
<event>
  <property1>721695632</property1>
  <property2>266</property2>
  <class1>
   <property31>dirk</property31>
   <property32>192.168.1.110</property32>
   <property33>fx</property33>
  </class1>
</event>  

Example 2
<event>
  <property1>721555130</property1>
  <property2>263</property2>
  <class2>
    <property41>00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00</property41>
    <property42>569</property42>
  </class2>
</event>

Example 3
<event>
 <property1>724342931</property1>
 <property2>326</property2>
 <class3>
  <property51>23</property51>
  <property52>00-00-00-00-00-00-00-02</property52>
  <property53>100.00</property53>
  <property54>0000AF72B7C12094EE833326234</property54>
 </class3>
</event>
```

The only commonality between the event notifications are the root node and the property1 and property2 nodes.  The remaining nodes vary between the different events. In order to deserialize the event notifications I created the following classes:

```
public class Event
{
    public ulong Property1 {get; set;}
    public int Property2 {get; set;}

    public class1 Property3 {get; set;}
    public class2 Property4 {get; set;}
    public class3 Property5 {get; set;}

}

public class1 
{   
    public string Property31 {get; set;}
    public string Property32 {get; set;}
    public string Property32 {get; set;}
}

public class2 
{   
    public string Property41 {get; set;}
    public int Property42 {get; set;}
}

public class3
{   
    public int Property51 {get; set;}
    public string Property52 {get; set;}
    public double Property53 {get; set;}
    public string Property54 {get; set;}
}
```

I deserialize the event notificaton using the event class.  After deserializing, I loop through all properties in event class in search for properties != null. There are always 3 non null properties.  Property1 and Property2 are alway guaranteed to not be null and either property 3,4, or 5 is not null. The non null properties are passed to this new class:

```
public class EventResult
{
    public ulong Property1 {get; set;}
    public int Property2 {get; set;}
    public Object EventType {get; set;}
}
```

Now I have a nice and neat class with only the valid properties.

This is were I'm trying to improve.  I would like get rid of the looping part and deserialize the event notification into the correct corresponding class with only the valid properties.

```
public class Event1
{
    public ulong Property1 {get; set;}
    public int Property2 {get; set;}
    public class1 Event {get; set;}
}

public class Event2
{
    public ulong Property1 {get; set;}
    public int Property2 {get; set;}
    public class2 Event {get; set;}
}

public class Event3
{
    public ulong Property1 {get; set;}
    public int Property2 {get; set;}
    public class3 Event {get; set;}
}
```

I was thinking I could use the EventResult class to deserialize the event notification; however, I don't think that would work because the XMLElement attribute is different for class1, class2, and class3.

I appreciate any help or discussion on this topic.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the classes inherit the Event class

```
    [XmlInclude(typeof(class1))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(class2))]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(class3))]
    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "event")]
    public class Event
    {
        [XmlElement("property1")]
        public ulong Property1 {get; set;}
        [XmlElement("property2")]
        public int Property2 { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "class1")]
    public class class1 : Event 
    {
        [XmlElement("property31")]
        public string Property31 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("property32")]
        public string Property32 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("property33")]
        public string Property33 { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "class2")]
    public class class2 : Event 
    {
        [XmlElement("property41")]
        public string Property41 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("property42")]
        public int Property42 { get; set; }
    }

    [Serializable]
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "class3")]
    public class class3 : Event
    {
        [XmlElement("property51")]
        public int Property51 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("property52")]
        public string Property52 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("property53")]
        public double Property53 { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("property54")]
        public string Property54 { get; set; }
    }​
```

Comment: Another excellent suggestion.  My actual code already follows your suggestion.  I put the common properties in abstract class that must be inherited by class1, class2, class3..........class36.  The only thing Im missing are the  XML includes and XML root above each class.

Answer (score 0):

You can deserialize directly to your `EventResult` class without needing any intermediate classes by decorating your `public Object EventType { get; set; }` property with multiple [`[XmlElement(String, Type)]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz6bdh5z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attributes, one for each possible subclasses of `object` that might be encountered as property values, giving the element name to use for each:

```
[XmlRoot("event")]
public class EventResult
{
    [XmlElement("property1")]
    public ulong Property1 { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("property2")]
    public int Property2 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("class1", typeof(class1))]
    [XmlElement("class2", typeof(class2))]
    [XmlElement("class3", typeof(class3))]
    public Object EventType { get; set; }
}
```

Then all three example XML files can be deserialized in one step.

For safety, I would recommend either

1. Making all `EventType` classes inherit from some base class or interface, or
2. In the setter for `EventType`, make sure the incoming `value` is one of the known types.  If not, throw an `ArgumentException`.

Comment: Very excellent suggestion. Thank you.   Looks very clean and simple.  Plus, when I pass the event result to my csv class, the get properties order usually follows the declaration order.